# On click calculate

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a simple calculation on click,

I want on every radio button a value, like 10,20,30 and if clicked it most count it up else not

```js
$('#1').click(function() {
   var first = 10;
   var second = 20;
   var third = 30;
   var total = first + second + third; //If isset..

   $("#total").val(total); // sets the total price input to the quantity * price
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=radio id=1>
<input type=radio id=2>
<input type=radio id=3>
<p /><input id=total></div>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? The calculation works fine for me.

Comment: Please post your code here as well, not just the fiddle...

Comment: Do you want to count it like this way- If button with ID 1 is clicked then in input 10 will be shown and then if button with ID 2 is clicked then 10+20 =30 will be shown and so on. Or you want to count like this - every time radio button is clicked 10+20+30 = 60 will be added and will be shown in text box (i.e.- 1 button is clicked value 60 will be shown, another button is clicked, value 120 will be shown in text box and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("#1,#2,#3").click(function() {
   if (jQuery("#1").is(":checked")) { var first = 10; } else { var first = 0; }
   if (jQuery("#2").is(":checked")) { var second = 20; } else { var second = 0; }
   if (jQuery("#3").is(":checked")) { var third = 30; } else { var third = 0; }
   var total = first + second + third;

   jQuery("#total").val(total); // sets the total price input to the quantity * price
});
```

Comment: How to make it counts on every click instead of only on `jQuery('#1').click(function() {` click on id 1

Comment: Oh nevermind i did `jQuery(this).click(function() {` and it works now Thanks! :D

Comment: @JohnSmith You can also use `jQuery("#1,#2,#3")` instead of `jQuery(this)` to it works only with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

HTML -

```
<input type=radio id=1>
<input type=radio id=2>
<input type=radio id=3>
<p /><input id=total></div>
```

JS Code -

```
var first = 0;
var second = 0;
var third = 0;
$("input:radio").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id')==1)
    {
         first = 10;
    }
    if($(this).attr('id')==2)
    {
         second = 20;
    }
    if($(this).attr('id')==3)
    {
         third = 30;
    }

    var total = first + second +third;

    $("#total").val(total);

});
```

JSFiddle URL - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/rgmyhamz/

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper I kept radio button's HTML code as same as given in the question.